# Trigger Android Button Default Animation

Tags: android, animation, button, touch, default

I have implemented a Button subclass and I'm handling the touch ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN events.

Since I have done this, I have lost the button's default animation on ACTION_DOWN (which just inverts the button colour I think).

How can I call the default ACTION_DOWN animation handler?

```
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )
      {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        {
          // Just to be sure that we removed all callbacks,
          // which should have occurred in the ACTION_UP
          removeCallbacks( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable );

          // Schedule the start of repetitions after a one half second delay.
          postDelayed( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable, initialRepeatDelay );

** How do I do something like this...? 
          //super.onTouch( v, event );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer - I just need to call setPressed() in the ACTION_UP/ACTION_DOWN states accordingly.